# Permutations - sum of harmonics with phases being another sum over product of index and its permutation

Tags: permutations, fourier-analysis, average

I am trying to calculate the following sum of harmonics: 
$$
\sum_{\sigma}\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Nk\cdot\sigma(k)\right),
$$
over all permutations $\sigma$ with $N$ being the size of the task.
Inside the exponents, the phases represent sums over indices $k$ multiplied by permutation $\sigma(k)$.
Because of this product, it is unclear for me how to handle the task.

I wonder, if there exist an analytical solution for that? 
I would appreciate any help with that.